# How to prove that $\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}\log(\vert 1- \exp(it)\vert)\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $r>1$ and $\displaystyle\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}\log(\vert 1- r\exp(it)\vert)\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)= 2\pi\log(r)$.

We want to prove that :

$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{r\to 1} \int_{[-\pi,\pi]}\log(\vert 1- r\exp(it)\vert)\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)=\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}\log(\vert 1- \exp(it)\vert)\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)$.

We want to apply the dominated convergence theorem. Let $(r_n)_{n\ge 0}$ a sequence of real numbers such that $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}r_n = \lim \limits_{r \to 1} r$.

- For all $t \in [-\pi,\pi]$, the sequence of functions $t \mapsto \log(\vert 1- r_n\exp(it)\vert)$ is continuous. So the sequence of functions is in $L^1([-\pi,\pi])$.
- $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty} \log(\vert 1- r_n\exp(it)\vert)=\lim \limits_{r\to 1} \log(\vert 1- r\exp(it)\vert)=\log(\vert 1- \exp(it)\vert)$.

Note that the function $t\mapsto \log(\vert 1- \exp(it)\vert)$ is continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]- \{0\}$ and in a neighborhood of $t=0$ we have $\log(\sqrt{(2-2\cos(t)}))=o \ (\dfrac{1}{\sqrt t})$. So the function $t\mapsto \log(\vert 1- \exp(it)\vert)$ is in $L^1([-\pi,\pi])$.

- For the hypothesis of domination I am stuck.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following observation is useful:

$$ \log |1 - re^{it}| \geq \log |1 - e^{it}| \qquad\text{for} \quad t \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and }r > 1 $$

Indeed,

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \log |1 - re^{it}|
= \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \operatorname{Re}\log(r - e^{-it})
= \operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{1}{r - e^{-it}}\right)
= \frac{r - \cos t}{|r - e^{-it}|^2} > 0, $$

and so, $r \mapsto \log |1 - re^{it}|$ is increasing for each given $t$.

Now, since $\log |1 - re^{it}|$ is squeezed between two integrable functions and converges pointwise to $\log|1 - e^{it}|$, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude.

Comment: Indeed really nice observation ! I tried something slight similar finally : I used the fact that for $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $\mathfrak{R}(z)\le \vert z \vert$. Then I want to prove that : $\dfrac{\vert 1- re^{it}\vert}{\vert 1 -e^{it} \vert}\ge 1$ for all $t\in[-\pi, \pi]\backslash \{0\}$ and $r>1$. Hence $\dfrac{\vert 1- re^{it}\vert}{\vert 1 -e^{it} \vert}\ge \mathfrak{R}\left(\dfrac{ 1- re^{it}}{1 -e^{it}}\right)=\dfrac{1+r}{2} \ge 1$.

Comment: @Maman, Your approach looks much simpler! Actually, I originally wanted to use the monotone convergence theorem, so that's why my solution contains a bit stronger claim than what is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_n \to 1$

You can assume that $r_n<2,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$

$|1-r_ne^{it}|\leq 1+r_n<3$ almost everywhere

Thus $\log|...| \leq \log 3 \in L^1[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: Thanks but I think it should be a $\vert \log(\vert .. \vert )\vert$ and the inequality is not verified for $t=0$.

Comment: @Maman its ok,because you can apply Dominated convergence if the equality is true almost everywhere.

Comment: Problem is still that $\log$ has not constant sign for $t \in [-\pi, \pi]$